# Protractor Exceptions Codes

Tags: javascript, angularjs, exception, protractor, end-to-end

I need to handle exceptions like `No element found using locator:` in my protractor tests so i can provide a better error message.

```
viewCompanyDocumentPage.getAttachmentType().then(function (type) {
    // Handle the success 
}, function (err) {
    console.log(err);
});
```

When i `console.log()` the error object given it has a value called `code` and has the value 7 for the above exception. I can use this error code to provide better messages. But where can i find the other exceptions that would be thrown by protractor element locators and what are the codes?

Answer (score 0):

One option here would to follow the Page Object pattern with the help of [`astrolabe` package](https://github.com/stuplum/astrolabe):

> Astrolabe is an extension for protractor that adds page objects to your functional/e2e tests.

Aside from other features, there is a convenient way to define your own exceptions with custom messages inside your page objects.

Also see:

- [Creating custom exceptions inside page objects](https://github.com/Droogans/ProtractorPageObjects/tree/chapter-4#exceptions)
- [How to handle element not found exception](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/631)

Comment: I am already using page objects which i created, Can i use this with out using its page objects and only use the exception handling aspect of it?

Comment: @KasunKodagoda well, I haven't tried astrolabe yet, it is on my TODO list. In terms of exceptions, [`astrolabe` uses](https://github.com/stuplum/astrolabe/blob/master/lib/astrolabe/base.js#L45) the [`exceptions`](https://github.com/allanmboyd/exceptions) module. You may want into it too. And I understand, that I haven't fully answered the question about the error codes and how to catch specific errors. I hope I'll look into it later. Thanks!